# With Jenkins Declarative pipeline, how do I set the value of a variable in a stage based on exe output output?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

With Jenkins Declarative pipeline, how do I set the value of a variable in a stage based on .exe output output?

The jenkins instance is running on windows OS.
The variable can either be global to the job run or local within a stage.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It looks like the key was to prefix the command with @ in order to prevent command itself from being included in the output

```
    stage('Build') {
  steps {
      script {
        //  Its very important to prefix the script with "@" or else the command itself will be included in the output
        GITVERSION_FULLSEMVAR = bat( script: '@GitVersion.exe /showvariable FullSemVer', returnStdout: true )
      }

      bat "dotnet build /p:Version=${GITVERSION_FULLSEMVAR}"
  }
```